# Hide + avoid loading specific files in visual studio code workspace

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have a Workspace navigating to bunch of directories that contains around 7000 files each.
How to hide all files of specific extension (and not load them, they are slowing PC extremely)?

so far:

````
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "directory1"
        }

    ],
    "settings": {
        "files.exclude": {
            "*.log": true,
            "*.lib": true,
            "*.sbr": true,
            "*.bak": true,
            "*.error": true
        },
        "files.associations": {
            "*.tsl": "C++"
        }
    }
} ```


But I'm still seining all the files on the left side in workspace tab.
````

Comment: Can you still reproduce this problem? Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.